# Lightgallery in slick slider detecting clones slides

Tags: jquery, slick.js, lightgallery

I am using [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) combined with [sachinchoolur lightGallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html).

I am running multiple sliders and I want each lightgallery to be related to its relative slider.

Which currently works, but the issue I am having is that lightgallery is getting slick sliders clones.

Normally I can get round this problem by using `infinite: false;` in slick, but in this case I really need my sliders to be `infinite: true;`.

I cannot get my head round this, is there a work around to this problem?

So only the visible slides, not clones, render into the lightgallery.

Here is a fiddle for easier debugging. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/jmvg5c93/

```js
// init slick slider
$('.slick').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});

// slick light gallery
$('.slick').lightGallery({
  selector: '.lightgallery',
  //selectWithin: '.slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned)'
});
```

```css
FIGURE {
  margin: 0;
  width: 300px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

IMG {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto 60px !important;
}

PRE {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<pre>4 Space Photos - lightgallery shows 9</pre>

<div class="slick">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/q5Y5RCH.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q5Y5RCH.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/8HjXPXD.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8HjXPXD.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/vUDcfcy.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vUDcfcy.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/okTDHas.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/okTDHas.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>

<pre>3 Sea Photos - lightgallery shows 7</pre>

<div class="slick">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/x7ZYW4i.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/x7ZYW4i.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/EYTCssm.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EYTCssm.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/3sAFPmL.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3sAFPmL.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>

<pre>5 Land Photos - lightgallery shows 11</pre>

<div class="slick">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/IqLrd0o.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IqLrd0o.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/6JplNl6.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6JplNl6.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/6X5GKWJ.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6X5GKWJ.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/SefTwI1.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SefTwI1.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/qBmDrTU.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qBmDrTU.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.7.0/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.7.0/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out...

```
// slick light gallery
$('.slick').lightGallery({
  selector: '.slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned) .lightgallery',
});
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/u5mh3a8x/